# find in db with explicitly excluded fields

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

How can I perform this operation :
[link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#explicitly-excluded-fields)

For example I want to get all documents but without field "name":

```
err := col.Find([]bson.M{{}, {"name": false}}).All(&result)
```

In result always will be 0 elements, why?(field name exists in collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Select

You are supposed to use something like:

```
err := col.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"name": 0}).All(&result)
```